# Answer own question preview box links to wrong text box

Tags: bug, status-completed

When entering a question and answer at the same time (i.e. "Answer your own question" is checked), if you click the in the preview box for the answer, focus jumps to the text box containing the markdown for the *question*. Focus should jump to the text box for the *answer*.

Comment: I stepped through the minified wmd.js and it tries to focus on the correct one as the code executes (`h.find(".wmd-preview").click(function() { k.focus() });`, where `k` is `#wmd-input-42` when bound). When that click method is actually triggered, though, the `k` field is the root input (`#wmd-input`) for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.